# Host WPF Application(Caliburn Framework) Inside Winforms

Tags: wpf, winforms, caliburn.micro

We have an existing Legacy **Winforms** application which is old and hard to maintain. So we decided to re-write the application using **WPF**. Due to lack of resource, we plan to have a hybrid type, where new features will be developed in WPF and over the course of time will migrate everything from Winforms to WPF.

Now the problem is, how can we integrate WPF application that uses MVVM framework to be launched from Winforms application. I tried "**ElementHost**" control to host WPF application. But I dont know how to achieve it with MVVM framework. Tried with **Caliburn.Micro** and getting an ***null*** exception when the BootStrapperBase.Initialize() method is called.

Please advice.

Comment: Do you mean exactly databinding?

Comment: Nope. I mean launching/Hosting Wpf applicatoin from Winforms application.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the Caliburn documentation [see here](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/bootstrapper), there is an option where we can pass **“false”** to the base constructor’s **“useApplication”** parameter.
This worked for me.

This launches the application. I tried playing around passing a reference to the WPF applicaton which contains event and method.